# Hacer un Login en usando el active directory en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Buenas.

Tengo un aplicativo, web con conexión a base de datos siempre he usado la clásica autenticación de `SQLServer` en el conexión string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CapaDatos.Properties.Settings.LogisticaConnectionString"
connectionString="Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Esa es solo la cadena de conexión del IDE, la cadena de conexión de usuario se da en tiempo de ejecución a según el usuario colocaba su cuenta de usuario y contraseña de `SQLServer`.

Funciona bien pero ese no es el problema, ahora nos mudamos a una arquitectura usando `Active Directory`, y se dio una estructura bien sólida de a que tablas los usuarios tienen acceso y todo eso.

El problema radica en que tengo que modificar mi código para iniciar sesión a la web usando el `Active Directory`, con el usuario validado iniciar sesión en `SQLServer` usando `Windows Autentication` dependiendo del usuario que se halla logeado.

Eh visto que SharePoint Maneja `Windows Autentication` (Si alguien ha usado `Sharepoint` un Login Promp eso es lo que quiero) y lo hace como yo quiero, pero no logro hacerlo.

He visto en varios POST que utilizan `Impersonate` pero no veo donde se coloca el usuario o contraseña del usuario.

```
IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();
try
{
    TextBox1.Text = Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString();
}
catch
{
    // Prevent exceptions propagating.
}
finally
{
    // Revert impersonation.
    wic.Undo();
}
```

Ese es el código del `Impersonate`, primero no veo donde colocar el usuario y contraseña y segundo lo veo muy escueto.

Tambien he visto que se hace desde el web.config

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="password" />
```

Pero si se habrán dado cuenta, para mi caso (un Login de varios usuarios en un `Active Directory`) no funcionaria.

Cuento con vuestra buena voluntad.

Comment: Apenas pueda, daré puntos para esta pregunta.

Comment: ¿El proceso de login al sitio se realizará ahora con el usuario y password de dominio?

Comment: Si, y con este mismo usuario y password se tendrá que hacer el login de SQL server usando Windows Autentication.

Comment: ¿Y el login al sitio ya lo tienes? ¿O son ambos login los que hacen falta?

Comment: El Login si lo tengo, esta plagado por internet la autenticación usando Forms, el detalle es el inicio de sesión usando el usuario actual hacia SQL Server Mediante Windows Autenticatión, (Estoy repitiendo la pregunta creo...)

Comment: En el código de Impersonate que pones, no se mete usuario y contraseña porque está obteniendo esa información de `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`. Por ejemplo, el nombre del usuario logueado lo tienes en `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Exacto, ahora `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` es solo de lectura y no lo puedes modificar. ahí mi problema.

Comment: He añadido una respuesta, yo he realizado un proyecto de prueba y funciona correctamente. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver, tengo una confusión con la respuesta que le diste a JYass "El Login si lo tengo, esta plagado por internet la autenticación usando Forms". Entiendo de esta afirmación que aún estas usando la autenticación con forms, para validar las credenciales del directorio activo?

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez si es correcto.

Comment: @Pikoh Sigo teniendo el mismo problema amigo, sigue autenticando con los usuarios por defecto y no hace el Login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evalué el proyecto que dejo @Pikoh y esta bien hasta cierto punto, pero como indicas aún no cumple con la totalidad de tu problemática.

Me tome el atrevimiento de tomar este proyecto como base y le realice unas modificaciones para intentar acercarlo un poco mas a lo que necesitas, adicionando una clase llamada `Impersonator` que la vamos a usar cada vez que necesitemos acceder a la base de datos. Espero que esta opción se acerque más a lo que necesitas

1. Creamos el proyecto Web "WebApplication1" con 2 paginas `Logon.aspx` y `Default.aspx`
   (esta ultima seria la página por defecto).
2. Aseguremos que vamos a trabajar en `IIS` no en `IIS Express` (Note
   algunas diferencias en el comportamiento con el manejo del usuario)
3. Aseguremos que en la autenticación de la aplicación dentro de `IIS`
   solo estén habilitadas las opciones de autenticación anónima y autenticación
   por formularios.
4. Y ahora vamos a ver el código dentro del proyecto:

**global.asax**

> Se deja sin métodos (No necesitamos adicionar código acá)

**web.config** (Notese impersonate="false")

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Se crea la clase **Impersonator.cs** en la raíz del proyecto

Namespace

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Clase

```
public class Impersonator
{
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
    String lpszDomain,
    String lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
    int impersonationLevel,
    ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    public static string Domain
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["domain"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["domain"] = value;
        }
    }

    public static string UserName {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"] = value;
        }
    }

    public static string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["password"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["password"] = value;
        }
    }


    public static bool ImpersonateValidUser()
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(UserName, Domain, Password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    if (impersonationContext != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        return false;
    }

    public static void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        impersonationContext.Undo();
    }
}
```

**Logon.aspx**

```
<%@ Page language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebApplication1" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Impersonator.Domain = txtDomain.Text;
        Impersonator.UserName = txtUsername.Text;
        Impersonator.Password = txtPassword.Text;

        if(Impersonator.ImpersonateValidUser())
        {
            //Insert your code that runs under the security context of a specific user here.

            //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
            bool isCookiePersistent = chkPersist.Checked;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                        txtUsername.Text,DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, string.Empty);

            //Encrypt the ticket.
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            if(true == isCookiePersistent)
                authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

            //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            //You can redirect now.
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, false));


            // Logout impersonation                
            //undoImpersonation();                        
        }
        else
        {
            //Your impersonation failed. Therefore, include a fail-safe mechanism here.
        }
    }
</script>

<html>
  <body>
    <form id="Login" method="post" runat="server">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" Runat=server >Domain:</asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDomain" Runat=server ></asp:TextBox><br>    
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat=server >Username:</asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID=txtUsername Runat=server ></asp:TextBox><br>
      <asp:Label ID="Label3" Runat=server >Password:</asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Runat=server TextMode=Password></asp:TextBox><br>
      <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Runat=server Text="Login" OnClick="Login_Click"></asp:Button><br>
      <asp:Label ID="errorLabel" Runat=server ForeColor=#ff3300></asp:Label><br>
      <asp:CheckBox ID=chkPersist Runat=server Text="Persist Cookie" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx** (Acá se debe cambiar la información de conexión a SQL)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebApplication1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Impersonator.ImpersonateValidUser()) {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Trusted_Connection=Yes");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table", sql);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Response.Write(dt.Rows.Count);

            // Reestablece las credenciales
            Impersonator.UndoImpersonation();
        }        
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +50 Bien ganados, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que al menos mi base haya servido para algo :) Sigo pensando que no debería ser necesario todo esto y que con el `impersonate` a true debería funcionar, pero si con esto el OP ha conseguido solucionar el problema, perfecto. Un saludo. +1

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, el proceso no es muy complicado. En tu pregunta no indicas si ya tienes la parte de hacer el login contra el Directorio Activo. Si no es asi, puedes simplemente seguir el proceso explicado aqui: [Autenticación de los Servicios de dominio de Active Directory desde ASP .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180890(v=vs.90).aspx).

Una vez tienes la parte del login (muy importante la parte de `<identity impersonate="true"/>`, ya que es lo que hace que el proceso asp.net use la identidad del usuario logueado), hacer el login en el SqlServer es muy sencillo. Simplemente debes añadir en la cadena de conexion `Trusted_Connection=Yes`, para que se utilice la autenticación windows. Sería algo asi:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servidor;Initial Catalog=baseDatos;Trusted_Connection=Yes");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tabla", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Ten en cuenta que debes tener activado el modo de autenticación de windows en el servidor SqlServer para que esto funcione.

*Referencias: [Cómo: Obtener acceso a SQL Server mediante la seguridad integrada de Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bsz5788z.aspx)*

**EDIT**

Te pego aqui el web.config que he utilizado para mi prueba:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/"/>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
      <identity impersonate="true"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Login del Directorio activo ya esta como explico en la pregunta, si le pongo así como me pones logea como anónimo, si le aumento username y password logea pero solo como el usuario que le pongas en el Impersonate del Web config, y si no le pongo nada logea como IISUser

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver si como yo te he puesto te loguea como anonimo, entonces posiblemente no tengas activado el `<identity impersonate="true"/>` en el web.config, o tu forma de autenticación en el directorio activa no es correcta. Yo tengo una solución de prueba basada en el primer enlace que te pongo, y con la cadena de conexion con `Trusted_Connection=Yes` se me loguea en el SqlServer con el mismo usuario sin problemas.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver He editado mi respuesta para que veas como es el web.config de mi solucion de prueba.

Comment: Sigue sin hacer el Login con SQL Windows Autentication.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver lamento que no te funcione. He subido [aqui](https://expirebox.com/download/0c762323112147b511ff171bb3410610.html) mi projecto de prueba. Puedes descargarlo, probar si te funciona y estudiar en ese caso que diferencia hay con el tuyo. Lamento no poder ayudarte mas :)