# En una consulta SQL con Visual FoxPro ¿como un registro puede acceder a la información del registro anterior?

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación que esta construida con `Visual FoxPro 6.0`, en este momento necesito hacer un consulta que permita a un registro dentro de un SELECT obtener información del registro inmediatamente anterior para realizar un calculo.

El calculo es simplemente entre campos fecha, el cual le debe permitir a un registro determinar cuanto tiempo a pasado con respecto al mismo campo fecha del registro anterior.

La consulta que busco realizar es algo parecido a lo siguiente (simplemente una idea):

```
SELECT 
    fila,
    fecha, 
    (fecha - fecha<del registro anterior>) as tiempo_transcurrido
FROM
    tabla
```

Y el resultado que espero obtener es el siguiente:

```
fila    fecha                  tiempo_tiempo_transcurrido
1       2017-04-07 00:00:00    0
2       2017-04-07 00:00:10    10
3       2017-04-07 00:00:15    5
4       2017-04-07 00:01:00    45
```

**NOTA:** No puedo usar funcionas propias de `SQL Server`, `ORACLE` o `MySQL` por que estoy trabajando sobre el motor de `Visual FoxPro 6.0`

Comment: <del registro anterior> ¿te refieres a uno que recién registraste?

Comment: @PabloContreras, No. Es una tabla con muchos registros en la cual se establece la fecha y hora en que se hizo. Solo quiero calcular las diferencias entre cada registro

Comment: ¿El registro con la fecha mas alta? o ¿El registro con la fecha anterior a la primera `fecha` ?

Comment: Es sencillo. Simplemente a cada registro que retorne la consulta, necesito calcularle en una columna adicional cuanto tiempo ha pasado con respecto al registro inmediatamente anterior dentro de la misma consulta (ahora bien, ese tiempo esta determinado por la columna fecha de esa tabla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema, haciendo lo siguiente

Ordeno mi filas por el campo fecha y luego las enumero para pasarlas a un `CURSOR`:

```
SELECT RECNO() Fila, * ;
FROM ;
( ;
    SELECT fecha FROM tabla ORDER BY fecha ;
) as subquery ;
INTO CURSOR datos_enumerados
```

Luego uso el `CURSOR` para realizar las comparaciones que necesito:

```
SELECT datos1.*, ROUND((datos1.fecha - datos2.fecha) / 60, 2) as minutos ;
FROM ;
    datos_enumerados as datos1 LEFT JOIN datos_enumerados as datos2 ;
    ON datos1.Fila = (datos2.Fila + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parecio excelente tu respuesta en:
[Hacer un Login en usando el active directory en ASP.NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55353/hacer-un-login-en-usando-el-active-directory-en-asp-net/57506#57506)
sinembargo mi caso va un poquito mas alla. En cambio de usar una ventana de login, quiero leer el usuario ya logeado.

He tratado de leer el usuario con mi aplicacion pero mi aplicacion corre en un servidor web y me lee el usuario de ese servidor y no el usuario local del browser.

En otras palabras: Si el usuario ya se logeo en windows no quiero que se logee otra vez en el servidor web, en realidad no quiero que tome el dominio ni el usuario, quiero que me lea los grupos a los que pertenece o que me conpare el grupo que yo tengo para ver si el usuario pertenece a ese grupo.

Comment: Hugo bienvenido a SOes. Si tienes otra pregunta sientete libre de publicarla aparte. En el apartado de respuestas tratamos de responder la pregunta en vez de plantear nuevos casos.